# Building labels out of counters

Tags: cross-referencing, expansion, counters

There is a simple version to my question, and a complex version. First, the simple version: I want to generate label names by combining a constant string with a counter's value, something like what is done here:

http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2006-July/006599.html

```
\newcommand{\addnextlabel}{\stepcounter{foo}\label{bar:\arabic{foo}}}
```

But when I use this, I get a bunch of warnings about multiply-defined labels. It appears they are all getting named the same thing, using the highest value of counter foo. I guess this has to do with the order TeX evaluates things, as suggested by the answer in the link above. Can anyone do a better job explaining this than the response there?

Now the more complex problem, and what I'm really trying to solve: I'm using the lineno package, which has a `\linelabel` command that works much like `\label`. You can get the label's line number using `\ref{labelname}`. It's these labels I really want to number with a counter. I tried applying the linked solution to `\linelabel`, but I couldn't get it to work. Any ideas how I might do this?

Comment: Hang on a second. After thinking about this again, if you need to type `\ref{bar:7}` to get the counter number 7, why do you need the label in the first place?

Answer (score 8):

1. You need to use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`. This must be badly documented somewhere — lots of people make this mistake.
2. You might need to save the linelabel counter to a counter of your own, decrement it, and then `\refstepcounter` it again. (Hope this explanation's not too brief; I'm in a hurry.)

Answer (score 0):

your \addnextlabel works fine in standard latex (for me) -- you're presumably using one of the myriad packages that fiddles with the reference mechanism.

i would expect

```
\newcommand{\addnextlabel}{\stepcounter{foo}%
  \edef\baz{\noexpand\label{bar:arabic{foo}}}%
  \baz
}
```

to do the job for you, if my hypothesis is correct.

Comment: The original `\addnextlabel` doesn't work to refer back to the labels that it's trying to set.