# automatically decide when to uppercase - is it possible?

Tags: uppercase, sentence

Is it possible to have a macro that will know when a sentence ends? So to be able to automatically typeset something uppercase or lowercase?

E.g.

```latex
\newcommand{\ciao}{\ifBeginOfSentence{Ciao}{ciao}}
```

So that

- `...foo \ciao` → "foo ciao"
- `...foo. \ciao` → "foo.   Ciao"

There is a sort of solution in the package hep-paper.sty (l.1089ss).
It involves, as far as I can tell, forcing a known value for the `\spacefactor` at paragraph breaks and after full stops and the like and then looking for this value in the macro. Here is the code used:

```latex
\RequirePackage[excludeor]{everyhook}
\newcommand{\begin@sentence}{1001}
\PushPostHook{par}{{\spacefactor=\begin@sentence}}
\def\frenchspacing{%
  \sfcode`\.\begin@sentence \sfcode`\?\begin@sentence
  \sfcode`\!\begin@sentence \sfcode`\:\begin@sentence
  \sfcode`\;\@m \sfcode`\,\@m
}
\newcommand{\if@begin@of@sentence}[2]{\leavevmode\protecting{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifnumcomp{\spacefactor}{=}{3000}} or%
               test {\ifnumcomp{\spacefactor}{=}{2000}} or%
               test {\ifnumcomp{\spacefactor}{=}{\begin@sentence}}%
  }{#1}{#2}%
}}
```

However I think it prevents the use of `\frenchspacing` (which is ok in my use case) and I feel like it is unsafe or that it will not cover all cases, but I cannot pinpoint any real problem. Can anyone spot any issue?

Comment: this road will lead to pain and frustration:-)  the posted code only applies at the end of paragraphs which is the easy case as tex is running code there anyway, but even there automatically uppercasing the first letter of the following paragraph is impossibly fragile. if you don't want to ban constructs like `\textbf{This} ...`  which make the first letter hard to find.  TeX doesn't normally run any code at all at a sentence end so anything that injects code at that point will break something.

Comment: This would use the uppercase form after `\item` in lists, for instance.

Comment: Very related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15556/is-it-possible-to-automatically-enumerate-sentences-in-latex/15561, especially the [answer by Yiannis Lazarides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15561/).

Comment: Isn't it easier when you are writing the document to decide that a new sentence starts and uppercase the first letter?  Do you really want a macro for each word deciding whether or not the first letter should be uppercased? --- GOM

Comment: I'm the only one who hates when a WYSIWYG program corrects me, and puts as uppercase what I want a lowercase, even though I can correct it instantly? Think now that LateX is not a WYSIWYG program, so you could have source with phrases starting in lowercase (less readable, indeed), but surely you would have to leave marks everywhere to force capitalization, or  to suppress the capitalization. That is, a less readable and writable source.  Automations are sometimes just a drag.

Comment: @PeterWilson yes I agree, but I'm editing another person's document and they use such macros... :)

Comment: Their use of spacefactor is X/Y. Anyway:-  (a) `biblatex` tracks punctuation (beware: it is asynchronous; it is an entire mechanism, not one macro). (b) `\spacefactor` as markup will fail for cases and values not catered for; for markup, it is more efficient to have your own custom markup instead. (c) "... gave a paper at the A.P.A." - see the `"`? And "A. P. A." (d) if the usage rules are really, really simple, a macro could be written (but then you would need to check that it worked - infinite regression). (e) what happened to `\@`? (f) `:- `? (g) regex?? Test for `.<whitespace>`, not `.`.